# Scripts Working on Localhost (xampp) doesnt work on web hosting websites

Tags: dom, post, curl

I hav a php curl script to login a website and post data into it..

I use DOM parsing to parse some links and then post data..

The script perfectly works on my localhost installed ( with XAMPP ) but wen i upload the same php file on any web host it gives blank page without posting anything..

Plz help guys
( this is a snippet of the script
http://pastebin.com/20aVSbf9
)

Answer (score 0):

check if your url's are absolute and change them to relative paths.

Comment: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
Thx for the reply...and does this cookie file make any difference? In xampp i dont declare cookie variable...wot shud i declare in web hosting websites?

Comment: have you checked if cURL and all other requirements are installed and enabled on your webserver. you can check this with phpinfo()